# What is lwc doing to custom ES6 Proxies?

Tags: lightning-web-components, locker-service, platform-bug, es6, proxy

### The Problem:

I am experiencing broken behavior when I pass Proxies as Event details or as public properties.

Requirement: they need to wrap a `{nested: {value: "Foo"}}`. I experienced this already while working with external libraries but it took me a while to find a root cause and give it a name.

This is a simple proxy helping me to take a shortcut through the nested structure:

[Playground](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/lvSde2t3jZmD6qab4b5R)

```
const proxy = new Proxy({nested: {value: "Foo"}}, {
    get(nestedObject, key) {
        return nestedObject.nested[key];
    },
    set(nestedObject, key, value) {
        nestedObject.nested[key] = value;
        return true;
    }
});

console.log(proxy.value); // "Foo"
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("proxychanged", {detail: proxy}))
```

doing the same in the event handler of the parent component right after dispatching it, results in:

```
handler({detail: proxy})
    console.log(proxy.value); // undefined
}
```

### What I discovered so far:

- my first log is asking the Proxy to get the given key `value`
- my second log is asking the Proxy to get the nesting key `nested`

this is odd and is only happening in SF context. Open source lwcs work as expected (as seen in the linked [Playground](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/lvSde2t3jZmD6qab4b5R))

I assume it's the locker service or some related features trying to encapsulate parameters/properties.
This is the stack that is accessing the proxy during dispatching the event. After that, it's broken.

[image]

### Question:

Can I prevent this somehow? Are there ways or best practices, to make the proxy more robust against this kind of injection?

Comment: I would assume this is a problem with LWC/LockerService proxy not supporting this pattern (the framework has its own proxy to allow observation and reactive behaviour).

Comment: the base functions (like reactive stuff) seem to work without this injection, since the OSS Version of lwc does not need this change. Also, it does not feel like it's a security "feature", because it does not provide any feedback or documentation, but just behaves very odd. But yes, I am also assuming it's coming from the locker service, but I guess it might be a bug or at least something that is not wanted that way.